# How do I store up to 2 names into my variables if needed and also how do I escape a possible single quote in a name?

Tags: bash, grep

`PhoneBook.txt` has names delimited by `:`

```
ex= first:last:number            - simple
ex= first first:last last:number - 2 firstnames and/or 2 last names
ex= f'irst:l'ast:number          - first name or last name with a single quote in it.
```

**My current script**

```
#!/bin/bash

firstName="$1"

lastName="$2"

if [[ "$firstName" == "" ]]; then

    read -p "Please enter a first name: " firstName

fi

if [[ "$lastName" == "" ]]; then

    read -p "Please enter a last name: " lastName

fi

grep "$firstName:$lastName" PhoneBook.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-F` argument tells `grep` to search for a fixed string instead of a regex.

Comment: @ 

Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams I added that to my grep statement but it still won't work if try to use phonebook from the command line. ex ./phonebook first first last last. But the program can handle 2 firsts or 2 last and single quotes when done through the prompt I just don't know how to do the same thing from the command line.

Comment: Passing multiple words passes multiple arguments. Quote or escape the spaces.

Comment: How would I do that for instances of a single quote in names?

Comment: Could I add an escape to my variables so a user can just type away. Ex= firstName="$1\" Something like that maybe?

Comment: Nothing in your script is causing the problem, and nothing in your script can fix it.

Comment: Yea that's kind of what I was afraid of. I was just trying to make the script more user friendly and as I don't know a lot about scripting I was working an unsolvable problem I think. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Use *double quotes* to delimit your arguments on the command line, e.g.:

```
./phonebook "first1 first2" "last o'last"
```

- You're free to use single quotes in a double-quoted string.
- Just be aware that double-quoted strings are subject to parameter (variable) and command substitution, so instances of literal `$` chars. must be escaped as `\$`.
- Similarly, embedded double quotes must be escaped as `\"`.

Note that, by contrast, there is *no direct way to embed single quotes in a single-quoted string* - you have to break the string apart and insert an escaped single quote, `\'`; e.g., to single-quote `isn't`, use `'isn'\''t'`; however, you can freely embed *double* quotes.

Comment: Good stuff to know! I think however that I am trying to make it too user friendly and what I think I am trying to accomplish is not something I can accomplish! Thank you for the good information!